# Upgrading an SSIS package that uses and encrypted password from 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I was tasked to upgrade some old SSIS packages from 2008 to 2012 and I have never done that before.

Most are upgraded automatically by the Visual Studio upgrade wizard, but one is failing and I think it's because it's using an encrypted password.

Here's the message:

> Error 0xc0016016: RiskWantedPosition: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.
>
> Error 0xc001f429: Package Upgrade: The loading of the package RiskWantedPosition.TA.dtsx has failed.

Anyone know what I have to do in order to upgrade successfully that package?

Comment: That particular error message is all over the internet. What is the _package protection level_?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid `ProtectionLevel` is set to `1` if I check the dtsx package in notepad. I tried changing to 0, 2, 3 and 4 but it didn't work. Also I tried changing the `CreatorName` to my username (suggestion found from other posts) without success too.

Comment: Unless you can log in as the original user, there is no way to retrieve the password. The next thing to do is set the encryption level to 0 which should at least allow you to open the package. Assuming that you can't actually open the package in SSDT to set it to 0, you could try doing it on the command line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/set-or-change-the-protection-level-of-packages?view=sql-server-2014#to-set-or-change-the-protection-level-of-packages-at-the-command-prompt although I'll guess that it will also throw this error